# Rails 4: How to add/subtract multiples of quarters to Date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

To get the start and end dates of the current quarter one could do:

```
start_of_curr_quarter = Time.current.to_date.beginning_of_quarter
end_of_curr_quarter = start_of_curr_quarter.end_of_quarter
```

To get the dates of the previous quarter, this seems to be a reasonable approach:

```
end_of_prev_quarter = Time.current.to_date.beginning_of_quarter - 1
start_of_prev_quarter = end_of_prev_quarter.beginning_of_quarter
```

I would like to generalize this. How would you implement the following function in Rails 4?

```
def quarter_dates(quarter_offset)
  # --------------------------------------------  
  #    quarter_offset        return value
  # --------------------------------------------
  #          0           current quarter dates
  #          1             prev quarter dates
  #          2         before prev quarter dates
  #         ...                   ...

  # Implementation goes here...

  [start_of_quarter, end_of_quarter]
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
def quarter_dates(offset)
  date = Date.today << (offset * 3)
  [date.beginning_of_quarter, date.end_of_quarter]
end

puts quarter_dates(0) #=> [Tue, 01 Apr 2014, Mon, 30 Jun 2014]
puts quarter_dates(1) #=> [Wed, 01 Jan 2014, Mon, 31 Mar 2014]
puts quarter_dates(9) #=> [Sun, 01 Jan 2012, Sat, 31 Mar 2012]
```

Comment: @spickermann: Your solution assumes that 1 month is always 30 days. Suppose that `Date.today = Date.new(2014, 9, 30)` and `offset = 1`. You'll get `date.beginning_of_quarter = 1 Apr 2014` which is the beginning of the current quarter, not the previous one!

Comment: @MishaMoroshko: I am sorry, but I think you are wrong. '2014-09-30' is the last day of the third quarter. Therefore the previous quarter is the second quarter. The beginning of the second quarter is '2014-04-01' (and its ends on '2014-06-30'). Exactly what my method returns. Furthermore `<<` is a Ruby method that does not assume 30 days or similar. Please take your time to review your comment.

Comment: @spickermann: I am sorry, but I think you are right!! Very elegant solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using Rails my solution is

```
def quarter_dates(quarter_offset = 0)
  quarter_start = Time.now.to_date.beginning_of_quarter - (3 * quarter_offset).months
  quarter_end = quarter_start.end_of_quarter
  [quarter_start,quarter_end]
end
```

I personally would prefer to use `+ (3*quarter_offset).months` and use negative offsets for previous months though.

Comment: 3 months is not always 1 quarter of a year.

Comment: @JohnC, provide an example, please

Comment: Sorry, your function works great. If you do a quick edit I will remove my down vote.

Answer (score 2):

I assume positive offsets for future and negative offsets for past. You can make negative offsets for future and positive offsets for the past by replacing `months_since` with `months_ago`.

You can also optionally pass a day if you wish to get quarters relative  to it.

```
def quarter_dates offset=0, date_day=Date.today
  temp = date_day.months_since(3 * offset)
  [temp.beginning_of_quarter, temp.end_of_quarter]
end
```

Test:

```
quarter_dates # => [Tue, 01 Apr 2014, Mon, 30 Jun 2014] 
quarter_dates -1 # => [Wed, 01 Jan 2014, Mon, 31 Mar 2014]
quarter_dates -2, Date.new(2013,1,1) # => [Sun, 01 Jul 2012, Sun, 30 Sep 2012] 
quarter_dates 1, Date.new(2013,9,30) # => [Tue, 01 Oct 2013, Tue, 31 Dec 2013]
```

Comment: This fails for jan 1 and sep 30

Comment: @JohnC There is no quarter that begins with Jan 1 and ends with Sep 30. I think you mean the third quarter which begins with Jul 1 (the sixth month) and ends with Sep 30 (last day of the ninth month) which perfectly works for me. What does it give you?

Comment: I mean set your date to jan 1 and subtract a quarter.  Same for sep 30.  In my solution I posted an rspec test suite which will do this for you.  Please feel free to try it.

Comment: @JohnC That's right, I just forgot to flip between the two possible ways. It's fixed now, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, my spec doesn't work for your function because it doesn't stub Date.today

Comment: @JohnC You can try it in the `rails console` man, I for one don't always unit test everything.

Comment: try: `Date.stub(:today) { Date.new(2013,1,1) }`?

Answer (score 2):

### Add a `.quarter` initializer method to `Integer`.

In our case we were just interested in being able to add a quarter to a `Date` or `Time` as easily as we do with a month. So we added an initializer that adds the `quarter` method to the `Integer` class:

**config/initializers/quarter.rb**

```
class Integer

  # Add a quarter method to handle adding and subtracting quarters easily, just like we already can with months.
  # Each quarter is equivalent to 3.months.
  #
  # Use in singular form, like Date.today + 1.quarter, or in plural form, like Date.today + 3.quarters.
  #
  def quarter
    ( self * 3 ).months
  end
  alias quarters quarter

end
```

Then you can easily call it like you do with `.days`, `.months`, etc.

```
> Date.today
#=> Mon, 02 Dec 2019
> Date.today + 1.quarter
#=> Mon, 02 Mar 2020
> Date.today + 2.quarters
#=> Tue, 02 Jun 2020
> Date.today + 3.quarters
#=> Wed, 02 Sep 2020
> Date.today + 4.quarters
#=> Wed, 02 Dec 2020
```

If you looking for the start and end of a quarter, you can combine this with `beginning_of_quarter` and `end_of_quarter` to easily jump to a quarter and get your start and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
def quarter_dates(quarter_offset = 0) 
  current_date               = Time.current.to_date
  offset_years, offset_month = (current_date.month - (quarter_offset + 1) * 3 ).divmod(12) 
  start_of_quarter           = current_date.beginning_of_month.change(
                   month: [10, 7, 4, 1].detect { |m| m <= offset_month + 1}, 
                   year:  current_date.year + offset_years
  )

  [start_of_quarter, start_of_quarter.end_of_quarter]
end
```

Inspired by http://apidock.com/rails/Date/beginning_of_quarter source code

```
quarter_dates   => [Tue, 01 Apr 2014, Mon, 30 Jun 2014]
quarter_dates 1 => [Wed, 01 Jan 2014, Mon, 31 Mar 2014]
quarter_dates 9 => [Sun, 01 Jan 2012, Sat, 31 Mar 2012]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to working in month numbers and avoid using ruby months. This is ugly, but I think it works

```
def quarter_dates(quarter_offset = 0)
  time = Time.now
  current_quarter = (time.month - 1) / 3
  normalised_offset = current_quarter - quarter_offset
  offset_quarter = normalised_offset % 4
  year_offset = normalised_offset / 4
  offset_year = time.year + year_offset
  quarter_start_month = 3 * (offset_quarter) + 1
  next_quarter_start_month = quarter_start_month + 3
  quarter_start = Time.local(offset_year, quarter_start_month, 1)
  if next_quarter_start_month == 13
    quarter_end = Time.local((offset_year + 1), 1, 1) - 1
  else
    quarter_end = Time.local(offset_year, next_quarter_start_month, 1) - 1
  end
  [quarter_start, quarter_end]
end
```

It also avoids using rails only methods, so should work in any Ruby environment

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to just generalise the formula you used in your question. Negative offsets represent future quarters, positive offsets past quarters.

```
def quarter_dates(quarter_offset = 0)
  reference_date = Time.now.to_date
  until quarter_offset == 0
    if quarter_offset > 0
      reference_date = reference_date.beginning_of_quarter - 1
      quarter_offset -= 1
    else 
      reference_date = reference_date.end_of_quarter + 1
      quarter_offset += 1
    end
  end
  [reference_date.beginning_of_quarter, reference_date.end_of_quarter]
end
```

Comment: You have a typo in the end, `reference-date` should be `reference_date`.  I tried to edit, but apparently edits must be 6 characters in length.  :/

Comment: Thanks @RubeOnRails well spotted. :)  Typo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I ran into the same problem...
This solution worked for me:

```
beginning_of_next_quarter=Date.today.beginning_of_quarter + 3.month
end_of_next_quarter=Date.today.end_of_quarter + 3.month
```